# Replace all URLs with hyperlinks

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

I have following code which uses regex to find all the urls within a given string:

```
Dim regex As New Regex("(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Now, I want to replace all the matches with hyperlinks:

```
For Each match As Match In mactches
    strtemp &= strtemp.Replace(match, "<a target='_blank' href='mailto:" & match & "'>" & match & "</a>")
Next
```

The regex works fine but there is an issue while replacing.  Suppose my input string is as follows:

```
www.google.com is as same as google.com and also http://google.com
```

The code will first replace `www.google.com` with `<a>` and then, when the second match (`google.com`) comes up, it will again replace the previous one.  So, what is a way of achieving this?

Comment: why is this tagged c#? and in c#, strings are immutable. `Replace` returns the new, edited string but does not change the original one. I'm pretty sure this is the same for vb, isn't it? And what is `strtemp` and `value`?

Comment: is it cool now.. so you have any way to tackle the above problem

Comment: Instead of using `String.Replace`, use `Regex.Replace`

Comment: @StevenDoggart can you please provide some code so that i can work in that direction :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `Regex.Replace`, it will work correctly, since it will replace each occurrence as it finds them rather than replacing all other matches at the same time:

```
Dim pattern As String = "(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)"
Dim regex As New Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Dim input As String = "www.google.com is as same as google.com and also http://google.com"
Dim output As String = regex.Replace(input, "<a target='_blank' href='mailto:$&'>$&</a>")
```

However, if you are just going to recreate the `Regex` object each time you call it, you could just use the static `Regex.Replace` method instead.

The `$&` is a special substitution expression which instructs the `Replace` method to insert the entire match at that point in the replacement string.  For other substitution expressions, see the section on the MSDN [quick reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#substitutions) page.